# My code in Swift vs. Java. Swift gives an error but Java doesn't. Are there any differences?

Tags: java, swift, for-loop

So I'm writing an app that will find the prime factors of a number.  I'm writing the app in Swift but it gives me an error if i set "num" to an even number but not an odd number. The error says, `Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION code=EXC_l386_INVOP, subcode=0x0` on the 5th line of code.

Here's the Swift code:

```
var num = 16

for i in 2...(num/2)-1 {

    if ((num % i) == 0) {
        var isPrimeFactor = true

        for l in 2...i-1 {
            if ((i%l) == 0) {
                isPrimeFactor = false;
            }//end if
        }//end for

        if (isPrimeFactor == true) {
            i
        }//end if

    }//end if

}//end for
```

Here's the Java code(that I thought was an exact copy of the Swift code):

```
int num = 16;

for (int i=2; i<num/2; i++) {
    if (num%i == 0) {
        boolean isPrimeFactor = true;

        for (int l=2; l<i; l++) {
            if ((i%l) == 0) {
                isPrimeFactor = false;
            }
        }

        if (isPrimeFactor == true) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Also, did Apple get rid of the `..` in for loops? I get an error using those too.

EDIT: Wow. I figured out that my code just needed the ..< instead of ...num-1 to work.  Thanks for all the help to all the contributed!

Comment: Your problem is, that on the loop where you get the error the first time, i-1 is less than 2. So the code crashes. (check my answer for further informations)

Comment: And it looks much cleaner like this isn't it ?

Comment: One more thing. When i just use the code above with the ..<, it works for all numbers but 10 and 14. For 10 it only gives me 2 but not 5. For 14 it only gives me 2 but not 7.

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand. When using 0..<10 is the same as 0...9. It is really simple. So you have probably another problem at your method not related to the loop

Comment: Yes but this way if i is 2, it will still run.

Comment: I've being through the same process as you are right now and and ended up with the code I've already provided to you. I solved that using the ceil function

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out. I just neede to delete the -1 from the first for-loop

Comment: Leonardo, yes, I know your code does what my code is supposed to but I just wanted to figure out what was wrong with mine so I don't do the same error somewhere else

Comment: I know. This looks easy to solve but it is kind of complex. I even had to add that specific check if squareRoot * squareRoot == self { return false }

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, apple didn't get rid of the `for in` loops.

Your problem is, that line:

```
 for l in 2...i-1 {
```

Because if `i-1` is less than 2, this error occurs. So you need to make a check, if i-1 is equal or greater than 2. check this code to prove the error:

```
for l in 2...2 { //No error
for l in 2...1 { //error
```

So I would make something like that, if you want to keep your code:

```
if(i-1 >= 2){
    for a in 2...i-1 {
        if ((i%a) == 0) {
            isPrimeFactor = false
        }//end if
    }//end for
}
```

Also you have an error here:

```
 if (isPrimeFactor == true) {
            i
        }//end if
```

You need to either wrap the i into an `println(i)` or remove it.

Comment: Oh, I see. So should I make an if statement right before that saying if i != 2 ....

Comment: Exactly. but make sure that it also isn't 0. So I would make it like if i >=2. I add it to my answer

Comment: And on the other hand, Java will happily accept `for (int i = 2; i < 1; i++)` and execute it 0 times.

Comment: Wouldn't it be if i>2?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I've made a mistake. I thought about if i-1>=2. So yes, it should be i>2.

Answer (score 1):

You should never compare if a Boolean type is == true. if (isPrimeFactor == true) is redundant.

```
 if isPrimeFactor { ... } else {...}
```

You can create a read-only computed property to return a Bool value indicating if a Number is Prime or not as follow:

```
extension Int {
    var isPrime:Bool{
        if self <  2 { return false }
        let squareRoot = Int(sqrt(Double(self)))
        if squareRoot * squareRoot == self { return false }
        for i in 2..<Int(ceil(sqrt(Double(self)))) {
            if self % i == 0 { return false }
        }
        return true
    }
}

1.isPrime   // false
2.isPrime   // true
3.isPrime   // true
4.isPrime   // false
5.isPrime   // true
6.isPrime   // false
7.isPrime   // true
8.isPrime   // false
9.isPrime   // false
10.isPrime   // false
11.isPrime   // true

let myInt = 7

if myInt.isPrime {
    // do this
} else {
    // do that
}
```

Apple did not get rid of .. You have to write:

```
for index in 0..<whatever {

}
```

or

```
for index in 0...whatever {

}
```

Comment: Can you please explain what this is and how to use it?

Comment: Wow. That is really cool! Do you mind breaking the code down?

Comment: Which part you don't understand?

Comment: this is because you don't need to check numbers above the square root of the number it self. it will save you a lot of time processing it. sqrt function needs a Double as parameter so I just convert the integer (self) to Double.

Comment: In mathematics and computer science, the floor and ceiling functions map a real number to the largest previous or the smallest following integer, respectively.

Comment: so we take the result of the sqrt apply the ceil method to it and than we convert it back to int to be able to use it in the for loop

Comment: Oh ok. This will help me a lot! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should use `2 ..< i` instead of `2 ... i - 1`.

`2 ..< 2` can generates empty sequence, whereas `2 ... 1` causes error.

And you can simplify the code like this.

```
OUTER: for i in 2 ... (num / 2) {
    if (num % i) == 0 {

        for l in 2 ..< i {
            if (i % l) == 0 {
                continue OUTER
            }
        }

        println(i)
    }
}
```