# guard let in swift 2.0 playground gets error about optional binding... why?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, let

I was watching [this video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015-414/). At 9:40 or so there is some sample code on the screen that looks like the code below:

```
//Sieve of Eratosthenes, as seen in WWDC 2015

func primes(n: Int) -> [Int] {
var numbers = [Int](2..<n)
for i in 0..<n-2 {
    guard let prime = numbers[i] where prime > 0 else { continue }
      for multiple in stride(from: 2 * prime-2, to: n-2, by: prime) {
        numbers[multiple] = 0
        print("\"numbers[i]")
      }

    }
return numbers.filter { $0 > 0 }
}
```

When I type that into an Xcode playground, I get the following error:

> Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'Int.'

Why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "problem" here is the statement `guard let prime = numbers[i]`. The compiler complains about it because the `guard let` syntax expects `numbers[i]` to be an Optional which it can conditionally unwrap. But it is not an optional, you are always able to retrieve the i-th `Int` out of the array.

To fix it simply write

```
let prime = numbers[i]
guard prime > 0 else { continue }
```

The correct usage of the `stride` then looks like the following (after a long search in the comments):

```
for multiple in (2*prime-2).stride(to: n-2, by: 2*prime-2) {
```

Then final piece is then to change the `print`:

```
print("\(numbers[i])")
```

Comment: hm if i do that, then I get a different error on the line `for multiple in stride(from: 2 * prime-2, to: n-2, by: prime)` "stride(from: to: by:) is not available. Call the 'stride(to:by:) method instead.

Comment: @DaveKliman yes, but that has nothing to do with the guard. I do not know exactly what the issue with `stride` is, but the compiler says "error: 'stride(from:to:by:)' is unavailable: call the 'stride(to:by:)' method instead"

Comment: as far as i can tell it's an element from an array of Ints, so it ought to be an Int, yes?

Comment: Stride needs to be accessed as an extension integer.stride(to: by:)

Comment: This is so typical of Xcode. it reports an error with the guard let, but then when that's changed it stops liking the same stride statement that worked moment earlier. i'm definitely trying to learn how to use it, but it's not really always so clear about what is really at issue.

Comment: ah i did see something about how the stride syntax had changed with swift 2.0... so just curious, how would that look in the code sample above? also, why didn't Xcode mind it being wrong until the guard let was fixed?

Comment: @DaveKliman I do not know what `stride` is used for - therefore no idea what the correct statement looks like, but you have to call it on `prime` probably.

Comment: @luk2302 integerFrom.stride(integerTo, by: integerBy)

Comment: @LeoDabus yes, I do know *that* by I do not know what is supposed to do. But it seems the correct statement is `prime.stride(to: n-2, by: 2*prime-2)`

Comment: Progressive loop where by is the increment

Comment: in the original code example, `for multiple in prime.stride(from: 2 * prime-2, to: n-2, by: prime)` it looks like it's starting at 2*prime-2, finishing at n-2 and counting by prime... so there is a from, to, and by... the new syntax has no "from" it seems... so now i'm not certain how to encode that...

Comment: cool. that worked. but what about the missing from? how does the new syntax cover that?

Comment: @DaveKliman what values would you like to get if say "prime" is 8?

Comment: @DaveKliman not sure the stride I initially posted in the answer is correct - it seemed wrong looking at the final output

Comment: (2 * prime-2).stride( ... )

Comment: ah yes... if we look at the results of the code you gave me @luk2302, those sure don't look like prime numbers... let me try with Leo's code...

Comment: `for multiple in (2*prime-2).stride(to: n-2, by: 2*prime-2) {` works :-)

Comment: @DaveKliman yes but change it to (2 * prime-2) you can check this (old and new syntax) http://stackoverflow.com/a/29056761/2303865

Comment: thanks, guys! it's such a relief to get these answers after trying myself for the last 45 minutes.

Comment: @DaveKliman you might be interested in this one also http://stackoverflow.com/a/28731168/2303865